# How to make a WordPress theme (site) scroll horizontal

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

How to make a WordPress theme (site) scroll horizontal. Here is one of the example I want my site to look like http://www.lucky8solutions.com/about/about-lucky-8-solution/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as changing one simple setting, you'll have to rework the whole theme.

This will get you started:

```
overflow-y:hidden; //hides vertical scrollbar
overflow-x:scroll; //always shows horizontal scrollbar
```